# Why is my general selector for <p> overwriting my class selector?

Tags: html, css

I'm an apprentice in informatics and I'm having a problem.

I'm currently struggling to find out, why my class selector with the font color red, is getting overwritten by my general `<p>` colour? I also tried finding out if it gets overwritten when I write `<p style="color: yellow">`, but this works.

So this is how my HTML looks:

```css
p {
  color: green;
}

.Banane {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>HTML 5 Boilerplate</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <!--<script src="index.js"></script>-->
  <div class="Banane">
    <h1>Bananenbrot ist lecker</h1>
    <h2>Wieso auch nicht?</h2>
    <p>Wusstest du dass Bananenbrot aus vielen Vitananen besteht?</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I even tried it with !important but it still doesn't work. It just stays green.

Thank you guys!

Comment: `p` doesn't have `Banane` class

Comment: CSS is as the name suggests cascading. It's going to apply the first value it comes across. In this example the p element is the correct choice, the Banane class is applied to p elements parent not the p element itself. If no color value is set on the element itself (e.g. the h1 and h2 elements) then it will look to its parent for a value.

Answer (score 1):

In your case:

```css
p {
  color: green;
}
```

Although it's less powerful than `.Banane`, it affects only the `<p>` not the `<div>`, the parent.

The selector is very specific to `<p>` and it is affecting the colour inside the `<div>` only for `<p>`.

Answer (score 1):

Css resolves conflicts in order of specificity because p is more specific than the containing class Banane you get green text unless you specify that p inside Banane shall also be red.

```css
p{
    color: green;
} 

.Banane p{
    color: red; 
}
.Banane{
    color: red; 
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>HTML 5 Boilerplate</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
      </head>
      <body>
      
        <!--<script src="index.js"></script>-->
            <div class="Banane">
                <h1>Bananenbrot ist lecker</h1>
                <h2>Wieso auch nicht?</h2>
                <p>Wusstest du dass Bananenbrot aus vielen Vitananen besteht?</p>
            </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Elements inside of `Banane` by default inherit color from a parent, so when you added `color: red` to `Banane` class, `h1` and `h2` elements inherited the color red from their parent. on the other hand with the `p` selector you basically said every `p` element should have `color: green`, so `p` inside of `Banane` won't inherit color from parent anymore cause it has been selected by you.

you can see this in the `computed` tab in chrome dev tools, the color green is higher than the color red and it will get applied.

[image: css computed tab in chrome dev tools showing color property for p element]